# Get route name from path with wildcard

Tags: 8, routes

we've wanted to implement a policy to consider some URLs as whitelist, I've provided a config form to admin to enter whitelist Urls, separated by newline, it must support `*` ( wildcard).

sample urls are

```
/user/*/edit
/coming-soon
```

and my implementation

```
$config = $config_factory->get('mint_coming_soon.softlaunchconfigadmin');

$white_route_list = $config->get('white_path_list');
$white_route_list = $white_route_list ? preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $white_route_list) : NULL;
$is_white_route = FALSE;
foreach ($white_route_list as $route) {
  $route_name = $this->pathValidator->getUrlIfValid($route);
  $route_name = $route_name ? $route_name->getRouteName() : NULL;
  drupal_set_message($route_name);
  $current_route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if ($current_route_name == $route_name) {
    $is_white_route = TRUE;
    break;
  }
}
```

`$this->pathValidator->getUrlIfValid` **doesn't work on URLs with the wildcard**, my question is **how can I get the route name of Url which contains a wildcard?**

**Notice:** wildcard in this question is particularly `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/user/*/edit';
$route_provider = \Drupal::service('router.route_provider');
$found_routes = $route_provider->getRoutesByPattern($pattern);
$route_names = [];
foreach ($found_routes as $route_name => $route_object) {
  $route_names[] = $route_name;
}
```