# How can I get a route's name if I have the route object?

Tags: routes

I have a [route object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21Route.php/class/Route/9.1.x) (*which **may not** be the current route's object*) and I need to get the route's name, e.g. entity.node.canonical. I don't see any method to get the name directly from the object, nor do I see it anywhere when I inspect the object via Xdebug.

I know that I can easily get the name of the current route with `$current_route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()`, but how can I get the name of an arbitrary route, if I have the route object.

Comment: You probably mean by not the current route object the route is outbound. You can't get the route name from the route object. This is why they added the route name to [RouteProcessorManager::processOutbound](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21RouteProcessor%21RouteProcessorManager.php/function/RouteProcessorManager%3A%3AprocessOutbound/9.2.x). You can, however, use a route processor to store the route name in the route object to retrieve it later.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to use `hook_domain_source_alter()` which is called from an outbound processor in the domain_source module. Maybe it's best that I create a patch to add route_name to the data passed to the alter hook.

Comment: Alternatively, I did find another post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272190/get-route-name-from-path-with-wildcard that might work.